# Docker containers are still running even after stopping the Docker service altogether

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is the first time such a thing happens to me. I'm really scared.

I've been coding and testing a Django webapp on my laptop. The app is running on Docker, with docker-compose. Both the host and guest are Ubuntu 18.04. It consists of 3 images: Django+Gunicorn, Nginx and Postgres.

Nothing really fancy and it worked perfectly, until 5 minutes ago.

When I tried to refresh the page (accessible via 127.0.0.1) on Chrome Incognito, it got stuck on loading. Same thing with curl. At the time, I was logged into the Django container (to activate collectstatic whenever I needed it) and it was still running as usual.

I thought something was stuck somewhere so I tried to see if there's anything listening to the 80 port. Nothing really special:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      10815/docker-proxy
```

So, wanting to get back to coding as fast as possible, I tried to (sudo) `down` then `kill` the containers, to no avail:

```
ERROR: for xxxxxxxx_nginx_1  Cannot kill container: e94e64a75b1726ccd27623024a4223ffb3d77c6578b4d69f6240bea51e8e641b: Cannot kill container e94e64a75b1726ccd27623024a4223ffb3d77c6578b4d69f6240bea51e8e641b: unknown error after kill: docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:393: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
```

No problem, I thought, and I just `stop`ed the docker service: 
`sudo systemctl stop docker`

I refreshed the `127.0.0.1` page expecting to see a `This site can’t be reached` page ... only to see the webapp loading!

I tried to see what container are running to stop them, but `docker ps` returned this:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Which confirms the Docker **service** was down. `systemctl status` confirmed just that. I also checked if the serverside code was running. It is. I also tried to change some frontend code, and it loading the new version.

Can someone tell me what's going on, and how to stop this 'zombie' app from running?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I just had the idea to run `ps aux | grep docker` and here's what I found:

```
root      1661  0.5  0.9 670260 74136 ?        Ssl  17:47   1:15 dockerd -G docker --exec-root=/var/snap/docker/384/run/docker --data-root=/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker --pidfile=/var/snap/docker/384/run/docker.pid --config-file=/var/snap/docker/384/config/daemon.json --debug
root      2148  0.3  0.4 756640 34944 ?        Ssl  17:47   0:47 docker-containerd --config /var/snap/docker/384/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
root      4105  0.0  0.0   7508  4112 ?        Sl   17:48   0:01 docker-containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/7709ab085e470228c120eff4c9b36590348dac483a40d9b107cfb8d62146e060 -address /var/snap/docker/384/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock -containerd-binary /snap/docker/384/bin/docker-containerd -runtime-root /var/snap/docker/384/run/docker/runtime-runc -debug
root     10618  0.0  0.0   7508  4464 ?        Sl   17:57   0:01 docker-containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/3a689a845ef012584e46d631c053ca0a00dbe34bb430f5e52a4de879c7efe966 -address /var/snap/docker/384/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock -containerd-binary /snap/docker/384/bin/docker-containerd -runtime-root /var/snap/docker/384/run/docker/runtime-runc -debug
root     10815  0.0  0.0 425952  2956 ?        Sl   17:58   0:07 /snap/docker/384/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 80 -container-ip 172.20.0.4 -container-port 80
root     10822  0.0  0.0   9172  5032 ?        Sl   17:58   0:01 docker-containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/e94e64a75b1726ccd27623024a4223ffb3d77c6578b4d69f6240bea51e8e641b -address /var/snap/docker/384/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock -containerd-binary /snap/docker/384/bin/docker-containerd -runtime-root /var/snap/docker/384/run/docker/runtime-runc -debug
ahmed    26359  0.0  0.0  21536  1048 pts/5    S+   21:52   0:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

**EDIT 2**
After manually `kill`ing some of the processes above, the situation is back to normal. But still, I'd love to get an explanation if there's one.

Comment: Hello, I have a similar issue, did you find any explanation?

Comment: Hello @AndréPletschette! I regret to inform you that, no, I wasn't able to get to the bottom of this as it never occurred again ― and thus was unable to investigate any further. But if you installed Docker (and/or docker-compose) via Snap, I'd recommend that you delete those and install them following the official docker guide. I recall doing so, but I don't remember if that was related to this particular error.